# Как обезопасить запрос?

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Загнали на сайт вирус и я даже не знаю, в какую сторону копать чтобы найти дыру. Скажите, можно ли как-то через дырку к базе залить на сайт файл? И соответственно, если в этом коде есть проблема, то как ее испарить?

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="contact_form(16);"></button>
```

**JS**

```
function contact_form(id) {
    this.axios
        .post('/update/'+id)
        .then((response) => {
             // 
        });
}
```

**PHP**

```
public function update(Request $request, Color $color)
{
    $color = Color::findOrFail($color->id);
    $color->popularity = $color->popularity + 1;
    $color->save();

    return $color;
}
```

**PHP**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'сolor' => 'numeric',
    ]);

    $colors = Color::where([['in_stock', '=', '1']])
                   ->orderByRaw(sprintf("CASE id WHEN %d THEN 1 ELSE 2 END", $request->get('сolor')))
                   ->orderBy("popularity", "desc")
                   ->get();
    
    return view('color.index', compact('colors'));
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу тут уязвимостей. Тут используется query builder, который строит безопасные запросы. Потенциальная дырка в orderByRaw, однако тут через `sprintf('%d')` можно подставить только число. Загрузки файлов тут также нет. Ищите в другом месте. Смотрите время создания: `stat имя файла`, журналы веб-сервера и так далее.

Comment: Проблема в лишнем запросе `public function update(Request $request, Color $color)
{
    $color = Color::findOrFail($color->id);` учитывая что у вас роут сделал тоже самое

Comment: Обсёрвера нету на эту модель может это он создаёт файл?